# What are "DR$XMLDOCIX1" tables in ArcSDE?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms

I was wondering if anyone knows what these tables are in SDE?
I'm working in an ArcGIS 10.1 environment, Oracle 11gR2 database.

[image]

Comment: Tables aren't ever "in" ArcSDE, only in a database.  Those are Oracle tables, created by Oracle, for Oracle's Text implementation (used with XML columns) https://www.google.com/search?q=dr%24+tables+in+oracle&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: My mistake, meant to say ArcSDE [enabled] database. Thank you for answer! Clarifies a lot of things. Cheers